# Indexed view doesn't exist on the subscriber

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I am configuring transactional replication in SQL Server. The subscription is configured as push from 2008R2 publisher (distributor is the same server) to 2012 subscriber.

The object I want to replicate is an **indexed view**. The base tables exist only on the publisher.

The replication fails due to the following error:

> Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects or columns are not present on the Subscriber

It is true that the view doesn't exist in the subscription database. How can i create it without the base tables?

Answer (score 1):

The clue to this is in the error, which is telling you that it can't create the view on the subscriber, because the subscriber is missing tables and/or columns that the view relies on.

You can't create the view without the base tables, so make sure you replicate the tables and/or columns involved in the view to the subscriber too, and then the view itself can be replicated.

Comment: Not exactly. I know I can't replicate a view without the base tables unless it is an indexed view which is persistent physically on the disk.

Comment: The MSDN 'sp_addarticle' document reference doesn't give any indication there are exceptions for object references. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857(v=sql.110).aspx, nor does the 'Create Indexed View' article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx both of which state the referenced objects must exist in the database the view sits on.

Comment: I managed to replicate the indexed view as a table. It requires a unique clustered index on the view to work.

Comment: @BuahahaXD create that as an answer and mark it for future reference. 
 Also, welcome to the forum.